# Вывести популярные теги php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

есть таблица тегов:

```
id, title, slug
```

и таблица связи тегов с постами

```
id, article_id, tag_id
```

Как вывести 10 самых популярных тегов?

Comment: Связать таблицы. Сгруппировать по тегу. Отсортировать по убыванию количества. Взять необходимое число первых записей.

Answer (score 2):

Осталось дело за малым

SELECT tag_id,COUNT(*) AS tags FROM Table_tag GROUP BY tag_id ORDER BY tags DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: а как связать с таблицей тегов tags, article_tags связь между постами и тегами

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в таблицу тегов атрибут view, в него делать +1 за  просмотром поста с тегом либо странниц с тегом.А потом сделать order by DESC. На Laravel

```
DB:('tags')->orderBy('view')->take(10)->get()
```

Comment: нужно найти, который чаще всего встречается в постах, то есть в таблице связи article_tags